Blazer Wasm Singleton object not available in other razor components. Need expert advice
APologize for a long post here. My goal is to get UserProfile and make it available across my blazer wasm app so we can make decisions based on the profile settings and preferences like menu etc.
I have two razor pages. Home.razor and Dasboard.razor.
My UserProfile service is defined as below:
    public class UserProfileService
    {
        public UserProfile CurrentUserProfile { get; private set; }

        public void SetUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            CurrentUserProfile = userProfile;
        }
    }

In the program.cs I have this code:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserProfileService>();

Home.Razor is structured this way:
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider 
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject UserProfileService UserProfileService 
@attribute [Authorize]
...
...
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent content = null;

            var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

            if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
            {
                Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                    = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);

                var response = await Http.PostAsync("api/users/register", content);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var userProfile = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UserProfile>();
                UserProfileService.SetUserProfile(userProfile);
            }
            else
            {
                // Redirect the user to the login page
                Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/login");
            }

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Error during token acquisition: {ex.Message}");
         }
     }
}

Here I have verified the UserProfile is properly returned and it is also assigned to the UserProfileService property.
My Dashboard.razor code looks like this:
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject UserProfileService UserProfileService

<h2>Welcome, @UserProfileService?.CurrentUserProfile?.DisplayName!</h2>

...

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var name = UserProfileService?.CurrentUserProfile?.DisplayName;
    }
}

I am only getting a NULL in Dashboard.razor.My expectation is I will get the value I assigned in Home.razore in Dashboard.razore.
Can you folks let me know what mistake am I making? Deeply appreciate your help.
